# how to associate a filter to a servlet in app.yaml for Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, servlet-filters, objectify, app.yaml

For my app engine application, I want to assign a servlet to a url pattern, but also set up the Objectify filter as described here: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup.

In my app.yaml I've got

```
handlers:
  - url: /v1/*
    name: v1
    servlet: org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
    ...etc...
```

which is routing requests to my servlet just fine, but I can't figure out how to arrange for the Objectify filter to run on the same requests that the servlet is handling.

The [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) say "A filter is a class that acts on a request like a servlet, but may allow the handling of the request to continue with other filters or servlets."

OK, good, that's what I want.  But the docs also say "A single URL mapping can include either a filter or a servlet, but not both."

So... how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are run before servlets and they are not exclusive. Normally for a request all filters would run and then one servlet for given Url would be chosen and executed.

Create a new filter section in your yaml:

```
handlers:
  - url: /v1/*
    name: v1
    servlet: org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
  - url: /*    
    name: ObjectifyFilter
    filter: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
```

Note: it's best to have ObjectifyFilter run on all requests (url: `/*`) just to be sure that objectify is always initialised.

Comment: So basically if I use app.yaml, I need to set up an artificial hierarchy, with the servlet-mapped URLs below the filter-mapped URLs?  In my case, the only requests that will use Objectify are the ones mapped to the Restlet servlet.  Or I guess I could fall back to using web.xml, which supports mapping a filter to a servlet.

Comment: (Edited the example yaml) No, this is flat. Just create a new url section with mapping to filter.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  For those who are wondering, it IS possible to specify the same url pattern for both the servlet and the filter (e.g. change the second url pattern in Peter's answer to "- url /v1/*")